# Postgres 9.6: Inserts very slow after reboot

Tags: linux, postgresql, sql-insert

I'm experiencing a strange issue when importing data into postgres. I have an import script that runs once daily at night via cronjob on a Linux OS (`Linux 4.9.0-5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u2 (2018-01-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux`). The process reads a file containing about 2 million rows and inserts these into a table in batches (batch size 25.000). This takes roughly 2 to 2.5 minutes, which is absolutely reasonable. The table has 3 indexes and meanwhile contains more than 130M rows. To increase the performance I declared the table as `UNLOGGED` and disabled `WAL`. From time to time I need to upgrade the system which requires a server restart. This somehow affects the database as the data import suddenly takes instead of minutes about 1 to 1.5 hours. I couldn't find out any reason for this. What's going wrong here, any ideas?

Comment: This happened to me once. Don't really know why, but for me it was fixed after **restarting the postgresql service**. My thinking says that if you do not restart the service(even after a reboot), it seems  postgres keeps its WAL (Write-Ahead Logging). By restarting the service everything cleans up, so everything runs as good as new again. But, perhaps there's another reason. Anyway, try restarting the service instead of rebooting or restart the service after reboot.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your reply. This really sounds like a possible cause. I have found [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/server-shutdown.html) in the postgres docs which also advises to shutdown the server with one of the mentioned signals so that the database can _"relay the signal to its subprocesses"_. Tomorrow I'll set up a test system and see if I might reproduce the issue. As soon as I have any updates on this I'll get back to you.

Comment: Hi Dan, it worked!!! :) Thank you very much! You were right, the WAL process was running after rebooting the server without shutting down the db server properly, which results in an extremely slow import. If you move  your comment to an answer I'm ready to accept it.

Comment: Great!, i've posted my answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me once. Don't really know why, but for me it was fixed after restarting the postgresql service. My thinking says that if you do not restart the service(even after a reboot), it seems postgres keeps its WAL (Write-Ahead Logging). By restarting the service everything cleans up, so everything runs as good as new again. But, perhaps there's another reason. Anyway, try restarting the service instead of rebooting or restart the service after reboot.

Read the question comments for more info or this [link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/server-shutdown.html) that @user35934 posted.