# postgres performance degradation with no reason

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-performance

I've a strange problem with a postgres 10 database.

After restoring a table with around 2 million record  i tried to run a query to measure it's execution time since it has been acting slow on another server.

Shortly after the restore the query was executing in about 1.5 seconds.

After around one hour the same query was executing in 30/40 seconds.

The query is nothing fancy :

```
SELECT f1,f2,f3 FROM table WHERE f4=false
```

The planned execution is the same has before.

No writes has been done on the table and the server wasn't on load from other tasks.

How this is possible ? how can i investigate the cause of the problem ?

Comment: Could it be your logs? Or is something else hogging your resources?

Comment: Or something else with locks on the table?

Comment: Is there any table lock or there is an index missing for `f4`?

Comment: Most likely it's the WAL (Write-Ahead Logging). Try restarting postgrsql service. Something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48328237/postgres-9-6-inserts-very-slow-after-reboot/48349112#48349112)

Comment: Try ANALYZing the table.