# Postgres insert slow after snapshot restore but not after restart

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2

**My setup**

- Postgres 11 running on an AWS EC2 t4g.xlarge instance (4 vCPU, 16GB) running Amazon Linux.
- Set up to take a nightly disk snapshot (my workload doesn't require high reliability).
- Database has table `xtc_table_1` with ~6.3 million rows, about 3.2GB.

**Scenario**

To test some new data processing code, I created a new test AWS instance from the nightly snapshot of my production instance.
I create a new `UNLOGGED` table, and populate it with `INSERT INTO holding_table_1 SELECT * FROM xtc_table_1;`

It takes around **2 min 24 sec** for the CREATE statement to execute.

I truncate `holding_table_1` and run the CREATE statement again, and it completes in **30 sec**.  The ~30 second timing is consistent for successive truncates and creates of the table.

I think this may be because of some caching of data.  I tried restarting Postgres service, then rebooting the AWS instance (after stopping postgres with `sudo service postgresql stop`), then stopping and starting the AWS instance.  However, it's still ~30 sec to create the table.

If I rebuild a new instance from the snapshot, the first time I run the CREATE statement it's back to the ~2m+ time.

Similar behavior for other tables xtc_table_2, xtc_table_3.

**Hypothesis**

After researching and finding [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48328237/postgres-9-6-inserts-very-slow-after-reboot), I wonder if what's happening is that the disk snapshot contains some WAL data that is being replayed the first time I do anything with xtc_table_n.  And that subsequently, because Postgres was shut down "nicely" there is no WAL to playback.

*Does this sound plausible?*

I don't know enough about Postgres internals to be sure.  I would have imagined that any WAL playback would happen on starting up postgres, but maybe it happens at the individual table level the first time a table is touched?

Knowing the reason is more than just theoretical; I'm using the test instance to do some tuning on some processing code, and need to be confident in having a consistent baseline to measure from.

Let me know if more information is needed about my setup or what I'm doing.

Comment: Have you looked into [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-initialize.html)?

Comment: @jellycsc thanks for the pointer, that could be it.  I'll run some tests today using the initialization steps that post suggests, and update here with results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jellycsc's suggestion was correct; adding more info here in case it's helpful to anyone else.

The problem I was encountering was not a postgres issue at all, but because of the way AWS handles volumes and snapshots.
From [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-initialize.html):

> For volumes that were created from snapshots, the storage blocks must
> be pulled down from Amazon S3 and written to the volume before you can
> access them. This preliminary action takes time and can cause a
> significant increase in the latency of I/O operations the first time
> each block is accessed. Volume performance is achieved after all
> blocks have been downloaded and written to the volume.

I used the `fio` utility as described in the linked AWS page to initialize the restored volume, and first-time performance was consistent with subsequent query times.